# Cloud Firestore error The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. after Upgrade to 2.0.0?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, dart-null-safety

This is NOT the old doc.data['field'] vs. doc.data()['field'] migration issue...it's new (to me):

The following code is a common example in my project running fine for the last 8 mos in Flutter with Firebase. I'm migrating to null safety, and in upgrading my dependencies to latest versions the following code is returning the following IDE error:  "The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'."

```
  final CollectionReference openUserList = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('openUsers');

final newUser = await openUserList.doc(ownerEmail.toLowerCase()).get();
if (newUser.exists) {
  return UserEssential(
    uid: newUser.data()['uid'],
    email: newUser.data()['email'].toString().toLowerCase(),
    displayName: newUser.data()['displayName'],
    defaultFacility: newUser.data()['facility'] ?? '',
    phone: newUser.data()['phone'] ?? '',
  );
} else {
  return null;
}
```

When I adjust to the following, specifying the place in newUser as if it is a list of newUsers, it runs:

```
    uid: newUser[0].data()['uid'],
    email: newUser[0].data()['email'].toString().toLowerCase(),
    displayName: newUser[0].data()['displayName'],
    defaultFacility: newUser[0].data()['facility'] ?? '',
    phone: newUser[0].data()['phone'] ?? '',
```

No errors after making that change.  I haven't seen or found any documentation on this on Flutter Fire.  Did DocumentSnapshot become a list?

Is this related to null safety, an undocumented firebase change, and IDE bug or something else? My code example pulls a DocumentSnapshot, so there can't be more than one newUser, why require the [0] and since this coincides with my null safety migration it's happening along with a lot of other things. I'm worried that this is actually wrong, and it's something else and I'm wasting time.

BTW: explicitly declaring newUser as a DocumentSnapshot doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after reading the FlutterFire Docs and 2.0.0 migration a little more closely [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/2.0.0_migration):

The solution is just to define the CollectionReference more explicitly like so:

```
  final CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>> openUserList = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('openUsers');
```

Comment: And do that for querysnapshot, etc as you see in the link.  Magic.

Answer (score 1):

Everything remains the same but you have to add `<Map<String, dynamic>>` to any cloud Firestore class, for example if your code is like this:

```
CollectionReference someCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('someCollection');
```

you have to change it to:

```
CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>> someCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('someCollection');
```

The same applies to any class, for example, if you make a QuerySnapshot and your code looks like this:

```
List<Something> _somethingListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
      return Something(
        something: doc.data()['something'] ?? '',
      );
    }).toList();
  }
```

You have to change it to this:

```
List<Something> _somethingListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
      return Something(
        something: doc.data()['something'] ?? '',
      );
    }).toList();
  }
```

As said before, it applies to any cloud Firestore class